# SQL server doesn't install

Tags: sql-server, database, windows, installation, windows-installer

[image: Image of the error]

**What we know / I've tried so far:**

- It failed during installation. Everything else seems to be installed correctly except for "Database Engine Services" (Ignoring server replication).
- The installer [sent me here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/admin/troubleshoot-os-4kb-disk-sector-size#cause), but this solution doesn't seem to work either.
- The SQL Server service doesn't start.
- The following screenshot is what I see when I click on the repair:
  [image: Repair failed screenshot]
- Looking through the logs, this is the repair error description: `The SQL Server feature 'SQL_Engine_Core_Inst' is not in a supported state for repair, as it was never successfully configured. Only features from successful installations can be repaired. To continue, remove the specified SQL Server feature.`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't install **SQL Server 2019 Developer** as well because of other reason below:

[image]

> A computer restart is required. Please restart your computer and try
> the Basic installation again.

So, I restarted **my Windows PC**, then I could install **SQL Server 2019 Developer**.